# Shutdown doesn't work in latest Linux Mint Tricia

Tags: shutdown

Well I´m new in linux and I´m pretty lost... My laptop is an asus with ryzen 5 and gpu RX560X, maybe is only a drivers issue, but i don't know how to get what i need. Thanks!

Comment: please provide more details, how do you trying shutdown? open terminal emulator and try `sudo shutdown -k now`(if you are not root)

Comment: I tried with shutdown command and normally with hte button of Mint, in both the OS is shutting down but the laptop still ON with the screen in black. I tried shutdown -k now but it doesn't appears to be doing anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the same problem with kernel 5.3.0-53. Kernel 5.3.0-51 works fine!

Comment: Please go here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-hwe/+bug/1880041 and click 'This bug affects me too' so it gets more visible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my personal experience:

I installed mint tricia 32-bit (xfce, kernel 5.4.0-77) on my old (OLD!) Samsung NC10 about 6 weeks ago, and it was fine.

Yesterday I switched it on for the first time in 5 weeks, did an update, and then it would not shut down through the standard shutdown button from the menu. I did shut it eventually by keeping the off-button pressed for a few seconds.
I started it again. With the menu button it did not shut down, again, and by pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key I could see the messages scrolled on the screen --- something like the following:

After "Shutdown" there was a "kernel panic",

```
"not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
/shutdown: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file ..."
```

So I switched it off by holding the off-button, started it again, searched for the `.so` library (`locate libpcre.so.3`); I saw that there was one in `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` directory.

I just tried and copied it into a more standard path:

```
sudo cp /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 /usr/lib/
```

and then I tried to shut down through the menu button and it worked!

I tried once again, and it booted up fine and then shut down properly via the menu button. Hope this helps.